# Save a file into folder

Tags: ionic-framework

I know I should use any plugin. I currently use a library called gif.js that allows me to generate a gif.

```
//this is result of create the gif
url = blob:http://localhost:8100/c5b4bc73-e64d-4556-982a-537a7027a1e5;

<Img src = 'blob:http://localhost:8100/c5b4bc73-e64d-4556-982a-537a7027a1e5'>
```

I can see the gif without any problem.

I intend to save this gif in a certain folder on my android device. how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use FileTransfer Plugin

```
          const fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();

           fileTransfer.download(frompath, that.fsurl+topath,
             (response) => {
                    resolve(response);
                },
                (error) => {
                    reject(error);
                }
            );
```